# Flutter Onesignal Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging

Tags: android, flutter, onesignal

I'm trying to run my flutter application after added `onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.8` on my `pubspec.yaml`. I got this error:

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:{require [19.0.0, 22.0.99]; prefer 22.0.0}.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :onesignal_flutter > com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.6.6
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 47s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your android/app/build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
         // ...
         mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
       classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
      }
    }

   apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

You can also refer to [One Signal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) for more info.